# java- while(true) does not keep executing using JPA but works for JDBC

Tags: java

So I wrote a program where I have a email table and it contains columns such as id,user,recipient,content,subject,etc. I would be running this as a backend service for 24/7 to keep fetching records to keep sending emails.

It's something like this:

```
public void schedule(){

        Thread service;
        service = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {

                    System.out.println("Email service is ready");
                    email();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        service.start();
    }

 public void email() throws Exception {
        try{

            while(true) {
                readConfig();
                String portNumber = (String) settingsMap.get("COBRA_PORT");
                if (ejbCon.checkConnection(portNumber) == -1) {
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("failed to init EJB Beans on cobra port : " + portNumber);
                    stop = true;
                }

                List<Emailqueue> emailList=ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().emailrecord();


                for (Emailqueue obj : emailList) {
                    String emailStatus = "DONE";
                    String errormsg=sendEmail(obj.getRecipient(), obj.getSubject(), obj.getContent(),obj.getUlnodeid(),obj.getUser());
                    if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                        emailStatus = "FAILED";
                    }
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);
                }

            }


        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            TerminalLogger.printMsg("Exception: "+e.toString());

        }
        Thread.sleep(2000);

    }
```

So in `email` method,it fetches record from the table where the status are 'pending' and get it's relevant values and pass them as parameters.So if there are two pending records,it will fetch them and for loop each to send to their respectively recipient. It works fine.

However,I kept the program running and I tried inserting new record to the table but it is not picking it up.There's no error too.I thought `while(true)` always keep picking up records from the table if there are pending email records.

Did I do any mistake?

Edit:

Apparently the while loop keeps running and picking newly inserted records when I implemented with JDBC but with JPA(in this case),it does not keep looping.

Edit 2:

Apparently, the `while(true)` works now and I have no idea why. Although,the program will throw an communication timeout error after a period of time,probably because there's no record. Would need to resolve that.

This is how the loop looks like now:

```
 try{

            while(true) {

                readConfig();
                String portNumber = (String) settingsMap.get("COBRA_PORT");
                if (ejbCon.checkConnection(portNumber) == -1) {
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("failed to init EJB Beans on cobra port : " + portNumber);
                    stop = true;
                }



                List<Emailqueue> emailList=ejbCon.getSettingsFacade().emailrecord();


                for (Emailqueue obj : emailList) {
                    String emailStatus = "DONE";
                    String errormsg=sendEmail(obj.getRecipient(), obj.getSubject(), obj.getContent(),obj.getUlnodeid(),obj.getUser());
                    if (!errormsg.equals("")) {
                        emailStatus = "FAILED";
                    }
                    TerminalLogger.printMsg("Status  : " + emailStatus);
                }


                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193437/discussion-on-question-by-daredevil-java-whiletrue-does-not-keep-executing-us).

Answer (score 1):

I think its prefer use cron scheduler rather than using **while(true)** inside of thread. it will be more safe than **while(true)** itself.

Comment: I do not understand your answer.Please provide more details.

Comment: @Scheduled(cron = "* * * 2 * *")
 public void schedule() throws Exception{
  //call your method and remove while(true), and Thread.sleep(2000)
                email();
 }

Comment: @madqori `while(true)` should not be used in general. Always try a work around instead of using endless loops. It will most likely result in behaviour which is not intended.

Comment: what do you suggest? Pls advice

Comment: @A.A. Suggestions?

Comment: @Scheduled is Spring, not Java.

Comment: @Daredevil what I suggest is, try to use cron scheduler with interval of 2 sec like you describe above to replace Thread.sleep(2000), what kind of framework you used to develop this app (jax-rs, spring or..) ?

Comment: nice, if you are using spring. have you tried to use cron scheduler?